# obtener valor de xml a variable en oracle

Tags: oracle, webservice, oracle-11g

trato de obtener el valor de un xml que esta almacenado en una variable tipo XMLTYPE y guardarlo en otra variable tipo varchar, pero al tratar de usar la función exctract, me genera el siguiente error, ORA-31011: Fallo en el análisis de XML, me podrían ayudar por favor.
----codigo utilizado---

P_FOLIOUNICO---variable varchar para almacenar dato a extraer

V_XMLTYPE -- variable que contiene el XML

/entry/content/d:properties/d:FolioUnico --- ruta de donde extraer el valor

P_FOLIOUNICO:=V_XMLTYPE.extract('/entry/content/d:properties/d:FolioUnico').getStringVal();

gracias.

Comment: Debes agregar los namespace de tú estructura XML separados por un espacio dentro de una cadena de texto como segundo argumento de la función extract

Comment: Hola @nauseantparrot no se si ha esto te referias con agregar los namespace?                                                                                                                                           P_FOLIOUNICO:=V_XMLTYPE.extract('/entry/content/d:properties/d:FolioUnico',XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' AS "m", 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' AS "d")).getStringVal();